# Insert one time two table user for loop getting error

Tags: codeigniter

I want to insert script using CodeIgniter two table table1 and  table2. 
table1 insert one time date but table2 three times date using for loop but getting an error. Loop is not working, kindly provide some suggestions.

Thanks

**Code:**

```php
public function add_rdi() {
    $user_id = $this -> input -> post('user_id');
    $user_rdi = $this -> input -> post('user_rdi');
    $zoneID = $this -> input -> post('zoneID');
    $mtstock6 = $this -> input -> post('mtstock6');
    $tfstank6 = $this -> input -> post('tfstank6');

    $data = [
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'user_rdi' => $user_rdi,
        'zoneID' => $zoneID,
        'mtstock6' => $mtstock6,
        'tfstank6' => $tfstank6,
    ];

    $data1 = ['fuelstock' => $gtfb,
        'fuelrecrdi' => $gtfb,
        'stockrdiname' => $user_rdi,
        'vfstock' => $tfstank1,
        'vfstock' => $tfstank2,
        'vfstock' => $tfstank3,
        'hfstock' => $tfstank4,
        'hfstock' => $tfstank5,
        'hfstock' => $tfstank6,
        'user_id' => $user_id

    ];

    $this -> load -> model('Mechanical_model_rdi');
    $query = $this -> db -> where('rdiname', $rdiname);
    $query = $this -> db -> get('fuel_rdi');
    if ($query -> num_rows() < 1) {
        $this -> Mechanical_model_rdi -> add_rdi($data);

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
            $this -> Mechanical_model_rdi -> add_rdi($data1);
        }

    } $this -> load -> view('mechanical/Mechanical_add_rdi');
}
```

Comment: what is error ? , Check your log file .

Comment: this questions has an already answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47727051/multiple-inserts-in-a-loop-codeigniter

Comment: please share the error screen